# Permutation and combinations (Sheldon M.Ross)

Tags: probability-distributions

We need to divide **8** new teachers among **4** schools , how many such divisions are possible ?

I tried to solve this by the **Distribution Method** , that is :

$x_1$ + $x_2$ + $x_3$ + $x_4$ = 8 , which gives the solution as ${11 \choose 3}$ , is this solution correct ? Kindly help !

Comment: Are you allowing some schools to be empty? If you are not, then you are correct. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29#Theorem_two_2

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. 
Actually no further information is provided.. It just says " 8 new teachers to be divided among 4 schools.. " @Christopher

Comment: Your solution is correct, just keep in mind there are 3 'bars'